# Are C++ references guaranteed to use pointers "internally"?

Tags: c++, c++14

Looking at references in C++ I noticed that all implementations I looked at used a pointer internally.

Does the C++ Standard guarantee that a reference will use a pointer internally or would it be ok for an implementation to use a more "efficient" solution? (I would currently not see how it could be done "better" because when a new stack frame is created there's not really a bulletproof way to know easily at what offset from the stack base pointer the variable that is being referenced is at because the stack is quite dynamic)

Note: I do understand the difference between a pointer and a reference in C++ (This question has nothing to do with that)

Comment: Why should you care?

Comment: If you write `int a = 5; int &b = a; b = 7;` the compiler is free to translate it to `int a = 5; a = 7;`

Comment: Anyway, how could you even tell?

Comment: @StoryTeller because my weird professor asked us to write down the stack layout in an exam and I was like what when it came to references because he didn't specify compiler, architecture nor optimizations and I really wasn't sure.

Comment: @noob Perhaps you'd do well to just sketch something good enough and add a note that it's really platform dependent--but gets the message across that you know the basics.

Comment: @immibis well I must say I compiled without optimizations and looked at what sweet assembly does so I guess you're totally right it can optimize it out in a lot of places.

Comment: @noob For the purpose of a question like that, assuming they're pointers is reasonable unless you've been told otherwise. Just be aware it's not a great question.

Comment: If the reference *needs* to be stored, for instance when it's a member variable of a function parameter, it most likely uses the same representation as a pointer, i.e. a memory address. When a reference is a local variable, it often doesn't need any storage.

Comment: @noob If your professor did not provide more details, chances are that they were implicitly assuming a pointer implementation. Even in the academia, it is not uncommon to find C++ teachers which assume (and teach) far more than the ISO standard guarantees.

Comment: Side note: the object being referenced isn't necessarily a variable (it can be any object), and it isn't necessarily on the stack (it can be in the free store, or in a register, or have static duration).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean that a reference requires the compiler to allocate storage for a pointer, then that's unspecified.

> #### § 8.3.2/4
>
> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage.

**EDIT:** To record Martin Bonner's comment as a  useful, practical note,

> [F]or debugging purposes it can be quite useful to know what is going on "under the hood". (E.g. to answer questions like "why hasn't this gone completely off the rails?"). In practise, compilers all implement references as pointers (unless they can optimize the reference completely away).

Comment: This is correct.  However, for debugging purposes it can be quite useful to know what is going on "under the hood".  (E.g. to answer questions like "why hasn't this gone completely off the rails?").  In practise, compilers all implement references as pointers (unless they can optimize the reference completely away).

Answer (score 5):

No, it does not make any guarantees about how references are implemented. The C++ language only defines the semantics of references, not their implementation.

Answer (score 5):

The standard doesn't say how a reference is implemented, just how it works.

It also doesn't say anything about stack frames, that's another implementation detail.